# In Gtk2, what's the difference between "active" and "focus"?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

Specifically I'm interested in knowing what the difference is between a Gtk Window that has focus and one that is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Active" is a state (see the `GtkStateType` enumeration). A widget is always in exactly one state.

Having the focus means that the widget receives keyboard input, if any. Only one widget per top-level window can have the focus. Only widgets that actually can receive keyboard input are focusable, see the text for the `gtk_widget_grab_focus()`. I don't think that the actual window can have the focus.